# How to emit a Map object

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In the server side I have something like this:

```
const users = new Map();
users.set('id', { name: 'name' });
// ...

// then I emit:
io.emit('user_change', users);
```

In the client side I have something like:

```
socket.on('user_change', users => {
    for (let user of users) {
        userlist.append(`<li>${user.name}</li>`);
    }
});
```

But `users` is empty (`{}`).

How do I emit a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

socket.io (or whatever transport mechanism) is probably using JSON as the serialization format. Unfortunately, Maps and Sets and other ES2015 datatypes cannot be JSON-encoded.

```
let m = new Map([['one', 1], ['ten', 10], ['hundred', 100]]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
// "{}"
```

It’s very inelegant but I convert to an array-of-arrays on the server-side, transmit that, and recreate the map on the client:

```
let transitString = JSON.stringify(Array.from(m));
console.log(transitString)
// "[["one",1],["ten",10],["hundred",100]]"
var newMap = new Map(JSON.parse(transitString));
console.log(newMap)
// Map {"one" => 1, "ten" => 10, "hundred" => 100}
```

So in your case, I’d do `io.emit('user_change', Array.from(users));` on the server, and on the client, change the `for` loop to consume a map: `for (let user of (new Map(users)))`.

Comment: instead of `Array.from()` you can also use the spread operator like this: `...m`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Map object to an object array just like this:

```js
const myMap = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2'],
  ['key3', 'value3']
]);

const mapToArray = [];

for (const [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  mapToArray.push({key: key, value: value});
}

console.log(mapToArray);
```

With this workaround you can have some funcionalities from map just using the array instance methods (filter, find, indexOf...)